# Need a library that supports client-side Identity server authentication

Tags: reactjs, next.js, capacitor, next-auth, idp

I am using Next.js as front-end framework and 'next-auth' package for authentication with Identity Server 4. The problem is when I export the app for mobile using capacitor (ionic) it uses 'next export' option to build the static app, while 'next-auth' package does not support 'next export' option because it runs on server side. I need an alternate to 'next-auth' that is purely on client-side and doesn't require any server.